# movement in gazebo with .stl file

Tags: ros, gazebo, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i have a question, can i move an stl object sapwned in gazebo?, the stl file is a 3D hand, can i move the fingers? how can i do that?

thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47453/movement-in-gazebo-with-.stl-file/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. Models (robots included) are all able to be moved.

[Manipulation plugins](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/plugins/model_manipulation_plugin) and [actors](http://www.robotsim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animated_characters) in SDF-land and controllers in urdf-land.

You should take a look at the gazebo wiki in general. Every week it is getting more complete.

Assuming that your 3D hand has joints, there is a tutorial on the wiki that shows how to do [joint animation](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animate_joint). There is also the option of pose animation as well.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0